# Assembly Stack Register How to Trace or Get value

Tags: assembly, stack

I've been given this assignment for homework.
I literally have no clue where to start as I missed this class because of a surgery I had. I"m not getting any help from the teacher because he doesn't seem to respond.

Here is the assembly code displayed from info reg in gdb of the program. It's a function call being displayed.

He wants us to get the value of the different addresses and the purpose of each.

What I don't get is for example can someone walk me through the first one, rbp + 0x10.

How would I find the value at that address?

I thought taking what RBP points to now 0x7fff, ffff, e330 and adding 0x10 to it to get 0x7fff, ffff, e340 would be correct but there's no address displayed matching that in the info reg print out.

Any tips in the correct direction would be great.

Here is the assignment

[image]

Comment: usually bp register points to current stack frame, so value in bp,ebp or rbp is a memory address you can print using `gdb x` command.

Comment: Hi, please print the code as code, not as a picture. Regarding your question, you didn't give enough information to answer. While it is likely that offsets from *RBP* are local vars and eventually parameters (though x64 don't use so much stack), without the function code we can't tell what is used for. If this is a reverse engineering exercise consider editing your question to reflect that or posting on the appropriate site (there is a reverse engineering site on the stackexchange network). Thanks!

Comment: intel x86_64 has little bit different call convention, so you may find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) useful.